# JSF 2.2, annotated Managed Beans not found on Tomcat 7 with virtualClasspath

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, annotations

I have a setup, where I have a Tomcat 7 Server defined in Eclipse that has a link to a different Eclipse project via

```
<Loader
    virtualClasspath="<path to the classes of the different project>"
    className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
    searchVirtualFirst="false" />
```

in it's context.xml.

This different project contains annotated Managed Beans (JSF 2.2 beans, no CDI) which are not found at runtime. What do I have to do to get those Managed Beans working?

I've already tried to also define

```
<Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
extraResourcePaths="WEB-INF/classes=&lt;path to the classes of the different project>" />
```

Also I put an empty faces-config.xml to the META-INF folder of the different project.

None of these options are working.

If I define the Managed Beans in the META-INF/faces-config.xml, then it's working fine, but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried defining faces-config.xml inside WEB-INF?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no WEB-INF folder in the different project. It’s intended to be used as an optional module for my webapp, which shall not be packaged to a jar file while it’s under development.